# jquery validation in mvc 5 doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function () {

                $(".error").hide();
                var hasError = false;

                var code = $("#code").val();
                if (code == '') {
                    $("#code").after('<span class="error">Enter code .</span>');
                    hasError = true;
                }
                else if (code <= 1) {
                    $("#code").after('<span class="error">Enter at least 2 charecter.</span>');
                    hasError = true;
                }

                if (hasError == true) { return false; }

            });
        });
```

For null check is working fine but the else if condition doesn't work and goes to the server site validation

Comment: Why in the world are you not using the `[Required]` and `[StringLength]` attributes applied to your model properties so that you get both client and server side validation out of the box. (and `else if (code <= 1) {` means if the value of code is less than the number `1`, not the number of characters)

Comment: For the purpose of my project I am trying to solve all the problem using raw coding. And I am not using the entity frame work.
 I didn't notice that I need to use the **length** property.
Thanks a lot I got it.

Comment: Validation attributes have nothing at all to do with the entity framework.

Comment: Thank sir. I don't know much about it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Dalim use **length** property as shown below in else condition.

```
var code = $("#code").val();
if (code == '') {
    $("#code").after('<span class="error">Enter code .</span>');
    hasError = true;
}
else if (code.length <= 1) {
    $("#code").after('<span class="error">Enter at least 2 charecter.</span>');
    hasError = true;
}

if (hasError == true) { return false; }
```